# Change/Rename the Caption on Multiple Buttons within a Loop

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, I have 15 command buttons (`btn_1, btn_2, ... btn_15`) and am trying to delete the caption text in all 15 buttons upon clicking a separate command button. I am currently using `Me.btn_1.Caption = ""` to individually delete the caption of each button.

How can I can delete the caption of these buttons without having individual lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each button in a sheet by rotating through your OLEObjects.

This code will reset the caption in the current worksheet only:

```
Sub resetButtonCaption()

    Dim btn As OLEObject
    For Each btn In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(btn.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
            If btn.Object.Caption Like "*btn*" Then
                btn.Object.Caption = vbNullString
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

This code will reset the caption within every worksheet:

```
Sub resetButtonCaption()

    Dim btn As OLEObject, ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each btn In ws.OLEObjects
            If TypeName(btn.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
                If btn.Object.Caption Like "*btn*" Then
                    btn.Object.Caption = vbNullString
                End If
            End If
        Next btn
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: The first code reset the captions of all command buttons in the current worksheet. Can I just affect the buttons with btn in the name?

Comment: @Code123 Updated Answer

Comment: To reference the buttons named btn I used btn.Name instead of btn.Object.Caption. Thanks for the help!